# python mechanize odd .read() output

Tags: python, mechanize

I am looking for help debugging Mechanize. When I navigate to a page and attempt to call .read(), I get non-unicode result about 1 out of every 5 or so attempts. The non-unicode result looks like the following:

> úRW!¤cêLÒ0T¸²ÖþF\<äs `+€²Ü@9‚ÈøMq1;=®}ÿ½8¹WP[ëæåñ±øþûÚc!ˆÍzòØåŸ¿þUüþf>àSÕ‹‚~é÷bÆª}Ãp#',®ˆâËýÊæÚ³­õµÊZñMyô‘;–sä„IWÍÞ·mwx¨|ýHåÀ½A ºÒòÀö QNqÒ4O{Žë+óZu"úÒ¸½vº³ÔP”º‘c`Ç—Êâ#<31{HiºF4N¨ÂÀ"Û´>•ŠÜÅò€U±§¶8ÑWEú(ƒ‘cÀWÄ~‡ ‡—¯J$ÁvQìfj²a$DdªÐŠÐ5[ü(4`­ ŒÛ"–<‹eñƒ(‚¹=[U¤#íQhÉÔô6(î$M ²-Õ£›Œndû8mØïõ7;"¨zÒ€F°¬@Xˆ€*õäŠˆxŸÊ%úÅò= kôc¡¢ØyœÑy³í>ËÜ-¥m+ßê¸ïmì Ycãa®-Ø•†ê¸îmq«x} i¥GEŽj]ÏëUÆËGS°êõ½AxwÕµêúR¶à|ôO¹ýüà:S¸S‡®U%}•Cî3ãg­~QÛó´Ó]ïn[FwuCm6žš[«J®™›Ý-£A˜Ö€sµ1khí"”/\S~u£C7²Í#wÑ»@ç@sô,ÆQèÊôó®.ä(å*æ‡#÷»'õµ­{à˜Õ„SÒ%@ˆtL  †¸±¹åI{„Õv#³ëŠUG…s‡•·Aíí»8¡Ò|Ö«à4€¼dˆ¸—áÐåqA­‘ï $Õ[NØÖ£o\s£Z_¾^ Äóo~?<Ú¿Ùÿ]À@@bÈ%¶Á$¦G  oË·ò}[µ+>ðµ°ÍöÐµ?R1úQ–&PãýT¥¢ði+|óf«ú,â,ÛQã¤šÓ¢Ïì­ÙT£šÚAä¡³£

I have tried the normal Mechanize parser (`mechanize.Browser()`) as well as the commonly suggested alternative (`factory=mechanize.RobustFactory()`).

Any suggestions for next steps?

Comment: Is this gzipped site content?

Comment: yes, I set 'set_handle_gzip()' to True and it cleared the problem. However, I don't understand why it would correctly read the page _some_ of the time without the 'set_handle_gzip()' option?

Comment: Not all webpages have gzip enabled. If this solved the problem for you, post the answer and mark it answered.

Comment: The issue was on a single gzipped webpage. I didn't bother to check if it was gzipped because it worked intermittently without `set_handle_gzip(True)` so I figured it wasn't the problem. Problem solved but still puzzling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved:

If you are getting similar output, check the page headers as it is probably gzipped after instantiating the browser set `set_handle_gzip(True)`

Comment: Please accept your answer if you don't expect to get better ones. Click on the tick left of your answer.